# Access Append Query duplicates results

Tags: sql, ms-access, append

I have an Append Query

```
INSERT INTO SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_LOANNOTPRESENT
SELECT SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_2.*
FROM SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_2, IMPORT_CSV
WHERE (((SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_2.coll_key) Not In (Select [LoanIdentifier] from [IMPORT_CSV])));
```

It is supposed to append anything from the SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_2 table which doesnt appear in IMPORT_CSV based on the loan identifier.

There are many columns in the X2 table and i need them all appended.

As an example of the problem, if IMPORT_CSV table has 20 rows in it and 1 row is to be appended. it will append 20 copies of that row. it seems like its doing the `WHERE` check on every row and appending when it doesnt match. usually a group by solves this but access is informing me that i can't `group by` if i'm appending by asterisk. i would have to list out all the columns and give the particular one a `group by`.

Is there something else that can be done in lieu of that?

Comment: Yuo have cartesian product between both tables. `FROM SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_2, IMPORT_CSV` I suggest to use explicit `FROM JOIN ON`

Comment: What version of ms-access are you using? Thanks

Comment: that worked like magic. used a 'LEFT JOIN'. would you like to submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `IMPORT_CSV` in the `FROM` clause, only in the subquery:

```
INSERT INTO SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_LOANNOTPRESENT
    SELECT SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_2.*
    FROM SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_2
    WHERE (((SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_2.coll_key) Not In (Select [LoanIdentifier] from [IMPORT_CSV])));
```

I also recommend using `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`:

```
INSERT INTO SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_LOANNOTPRESENT
    SELECT SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_2.*
    FROM SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM IMPORT_CSV
                      WHERE SPLIT_EXPORT_X2_2.coll_key = IMPORT_CSV.[LoanIdentifier]
                     );
```

`NOT IN` will filter out *all* rows if *any* value in the subquery is `NULL`.